# Regex HTTP Response Header

Tags: php, regex, http-headers, httpresponse, instagram-api

i have an example http header response :

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
content-language: en
date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 21:20:44 GMT
content-encoding: gzip
set-cookie: ds_user=usadaida521; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 06-Oct-2020 21:20:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: csrftoken=ev0sLTzbC4WIIk2FKvGcLLyVqgiFXD3A; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Wed, 07-Jul-2021 21:20:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: rur=FTW; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: ds_user_id=35321243349; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 06-Oct-2020 21:20:44 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: sessionid=35321243349%3AP3jlNxxuIVGoJx%3A24; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 08-Jul-2021 21:20:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Secure
content-length: 685
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
```

All I need to get is :

```
ds_user=usadaida521; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 06-Oct-2020 21:20:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure;csrftoken=ev0sLTzbC4WIIk2FKvGcLLyVqgiFXD3A; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Wed, 07-Jul-2021 21:20:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure;rur=FTW; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure;ds_user_id=35321243349; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 06-Oct-2020 21:20:44 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure;sessionid=35321243349%3AP3jlNxxuIVGoJx%3A24; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 08-Jul-2021 21:20:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Secure
```

I use this REGEX :

```
/^set-cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi
```

But I get :

```
ds_user=usadaida521;csrftoken=zL2U5EvMG61MNnPaQUGjpK2qklE5uBQ2;rur=FTW;ds_user_id=35321243349;sessionid=35321243349%3ALFbjFj8eRIkr2u%3A21
```

Can you help me with it? Thank you
Best Regards, Erwin

Comment: Use this https://regex101.com/r/oY32xa/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript I would do this:

```js
response
    .replaceAll(/^(?!set-cookie).*|^set-cookie: /gmi,"")
    .trim()
    .replaceAll(/[\r\n]+/g, ';')
```

**Sample:**

```js
cleanCoockie = response => {
    return response
        .replaceAll(/^(?!set-cookie).*|^set-cookie: /gmi,"")
        .trim()
        .replaceAll(/[\r\n]+/g, ';')
};

$("#result").html(
    cleanCoockie("HTTP/2 200 \ncontent-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\nvary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding\ncontent-language: en\ndate: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 21:20:44 GMT\ncontent-encoding: gzip\nset-cookie: ds_user=usadaida521; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 06-Oct-2020 21:20:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure\nset-cookie: csrftoken=ev0sLTzbC4WIIk2FKvGcLLyVqgiFXD3A; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Wed, 07-Jul-2021 21:20:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure\nset-cookie: rur=FTW; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure\nset-cookie: ds_user_id=35321243349; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 06-Oct-2020 21:20:44 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure\nset-cookie: sessionid=35321243349%3AP3jlNxxuIVGoJx%3A24; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 08-Jul-2021 21:20:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Secure\ncontent-length: 685\nalt-svc: h3-29=\":443\"; ma=3600,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=3600")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="result" rows="9" cols="80"></textarea>
```